# How to create conditional for attribute that equals current month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to only show `<b>September</b>` if there is a challenge that has a `deadline`, `t.date "deadline"`, set for the current month?

**controller**

```
@challenges = current_user.challenges.unaccomplished.order("deadline ASC").select{ |challenge| challenge.deadline.month == Date.current.month }
@current_month = (@challenges).group_by { |t| [t.deadline.year, t.deadline.month] }
```

**view**

```
<% if @current_month[Date.current.month].present? %> # This is not currently being triggered even though their is a challenge with a deadline in the current month.
  <b>September</b>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined the group key as a tuple [year, month].
And you need to use exactly the same format when you pick the challenge from the list. I.e.

```
@current_month[[Date.current.year, Date.current.month]]
```

Comment: I was so close after hours of trying! Thanks :)